# Controller Redirect in Orchard CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I have a Orchard solution with new module added into that. Later, I have added 2 controllers and their views accordingly. They are named as HomeController and SearchController.

In the Home controller Index post method, I have a functionality to call the SearchController Index action method. But, when I try executing the code I was getting weird error like this, `An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor()' on type 'SearchController'. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (See inner exception for details.)`.

**Code for HomeController**

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection form)
    {
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Search", new { area = "OPACCMS", srchtext = searchterm, sorting = sortby });
    }
```

**Code for SearchController**

```
public ActionResult Index(string srchtext, string sorting, string Paging)
  {
    return View();
  }
```

**Code for Routes**

```
public class Routes : IRouteProvider
{
    public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes)
    {
        foreach (var routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
            routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
    }

    public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
    {
        return new[] {
            new RouteDescriptor {
                Priority = 5,
                Route = new Route(
                    "OPACCMS",
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "OPACCMS"},
                        {"controller", "Home"},
                        {"action", "Index"}
                    },
                    new RouteValueDictionary(),
                    new RouteValueDictionary {
                        {"area", "OPACCMS"}
                    },
                    new MvcRouteHandler())
            }
        };

    }
}
```

Any help to this problem will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please paste in the constructor of your controller. As the error message says - there is an NullReferenceException thrown from there.

Comment: Can you please tell me something more on this. I am not able to get what to paste.

Comment: Constructor of your `SearchController` class. Error is in there.